# String to list of tuples from file in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, io

I am currently reading from an input file with a randomly sized list of tuples, I am trying to get the incoming data as a list, however ever, whenever I try to parse it as anything other than a string i receive error messages.  The input files look something like this:

```
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

or

```
[(4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2)]
```

I am able to handle the input as follows:

```
handle <- openFile "test.txt" ReadMode
coord <- hGetLine handle
let alive = coord
print alive
```

However, this produces a simple string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: perhaps you want to use `read`.

Comment: I have tried `read coord::list` and `read coord`, I get errors on both.

Comment: If you want a list of something you have to surround it in brackets.  You want a list of `Int` tuples, so `read coord :: [(Int, Int)]`

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

As dsemi pointed out, all I needed to use `read coord :: [(Int, Int)]`.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works fine:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- openFile "test.txt" ReadMode
  cords <-  map read <$> lines <$> hGetContents handle :: IO [(Int, Int)]
  putStrLn $ show cords
  return ()
```